# how to add a fonticons in breadcrumb with routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

i have an angular base  dashboard application ,in the application dashboard page icon ,when i click the particular icon ,the icon should be redirected to the routing page with menu breadcrumb with that icon.Instead of displaying image have to include  font-icon in that section.

displayImg is for displaying image and displayName is for displaying name

Below code is working fine with image.now i have to replace with font-icon.
how to do this.

here is an working plunker code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vKekaq7pCAqOpdXXJJYc?p=info

In the example when you click the detail , home icon is in the menu,when you click the product ,product icon will be there,order means order icon will be there its all images, which is mentioned under particular route here.

```
.state('home.product', {
        url: '/product',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'product.html',
            }
        },
        data: {
            displayName: 'product',
            displayImg: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
        }
    })
      .state('home.order', {
        url: '/order',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'order.html',
            }
        },
        data: {
            displayName: 'ordericon',
            displayImg: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
        }
})
```

This is the breadcrumb library  have used for dynamic menu

Breadcrumb js:

```
/**
 * uiBreadcrumbs automatic breadcrumbs directive for AngularJS & Angular ui-router.
 *
 * https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/uiBreadcrumbs
 *
 * Copyright 2014 Michael Bromley <michael@michaelbromley.co.uk>
 */


(function() {

    /**
     * Config
     */
    var moduleName = 'ngBreadCrumb';
    var templateUrl = 'ngBreadCrumbTemplate.html';

    /**
     * Module
     */
    var module;
    try {
        module = angular.module(moduleName);
    } catch(err) {
        // named module does not exist, so create one
        module = angular.module(moduleName, ['ui.router']);
    }

    module.directive('uiBreadcrumbs', ['$interpolate', '$state', function($interpolate, $state) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
                    return attrs.templateUrl || templateUrl;
                },
                scope: {
                    displaynameProperty: '@',
                    displayimgProperty:'@',   
                    abstractProxyProperty: '@?'
                },
                link: function(scope) {
                    scope.breadcrumbs = [];
                    if ($state.$current.name !== '') {
                        updateBreadcrumbsArray();
                    }
                    scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
                        updateBreadcrumbsArray();
                    });

                    /**
                     * Start with the current state and traverse up the path to build the
                     * array of breadcrumbs that can be used in an ng-repeat in the template.
                     */
                    function updateBreadcrumbsArray() {
                        var workingState;
                        var displayName;
                        var displayImg = 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/home-icon-png-home-icon-31.png';  //Sampriya
                        var breadcrumbs = [];
                        var currentState = $state.$current;

                        while(currentState && currentState.name !== '') {
                            workingState = getWorkingState(currentState);
                            if (workingState) {
                                displayName = getDisplayName(workingState);
                                displayImg = getDisplayImg(workingState);//Sampriya

                                if (displayName !== false && !stateAlreadyInBreadcrumbs(workingState, breadcrumbs)) {
                                    if (displayImg !== false) {
                                        breadcrumbs.push({
                                            displayName: displayName,
                                            displayImg: displayImg,
                                            route: workingState.name
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        breadcrumbs.push({
                                            displayName: displayName,
                                            route: workingState.name
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                //Sampriya
                                //if (displayImg !== false && !stateAlreadyInBreadcrumbs(workingState, breadcrumbs)) {
                                //    breadcrumbs.push({
                                //        displayImg: displayImg,
                                //        route: workingState.name
                                //    });
                                //}
                                //=====
                            }
                            currentState = currentState.parent;                            
                        }
                        breadcrumbs.reverse();
                        scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Get the state to put in the breadcrumbs array, taking into account that if the current state is abstract,
                     * we need to either substitute it with the state named in the `scope.abstractProxyProperty` property, or
                     * set it to `false` which means this breadcrumb level will be skipped entirely.
                     * @param currentState
                     * @returns {*}
                     */
                    function getWorkingState(currentState) {
                        var proxyStateName;
                        var workingState = currentState;
                        if (currentState.abstract === true) {
                            if (typeof scope.abstractProxyProperty !== 'undefined') {
                                proxyStateName = getObjectValue(scope.abstractProxyProperty, currentState);
                                if (proxyStateName) {
                                    workingState = $state.get(proxyStateName);
                                } else {
                                    workingState = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                workingState = false;
                            }
                        }
                        return workingState;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Resolve the displayName of the specified state. Take the property specified by the `displayname-property`
                     * attribute and look up the corresponding property on the state's config object. The specified string can be interpolated against any resolved
                     * properties on the state config object, by using the usual {{ }} syntax.
                     * @param currentState
                     * @returns {*}
                     */
                    function getDisplayName(currentState) {
                        var interpolationContext;
                        var propertyReference;
                        var displayName;

                        if (!scope.displaynameProperty) {
                            // if the displayname-property attribute was not specified, default to the state's name
                            return currentState.name;
                        }
                        propertyReference = getObjectValue(scope.displaynameProperty, currentState);

                        if (propertyReference === false) {
                            return false;
                        } else if (typeof propertyReference === 'undefined') {
                            return currentState.name;
                        } else {
                            // use the $interpolate service to handle any bindings in the propertyReference string.
                            interpolationContext =  (typeof currentState.locals !== 'undefined') ? currentState.locals.globals : currentState;
                            displayName = $interpolate(propertyReference)(interpolationContext);
                            return displayName;
                        }
                    }
                    //Sampriya
                    /**
                    * Resolve the displayImg of the specified state. Take the property specified by the `displayimg-property`
                    * attribute and look up the corresponding property on the state's config object. The specified string can be interpolated against any resolved
                    * properties on the state config object, by using the usual {{ }} syntax.
                    * @param currentState
                    * @returns {*}
                    */
                    function getDisplayImg(currentState) {
                        var interpolationContext;
                        var propertyReference;
                        var displayImg;                        
                        if (!scope.displayimgProperty) {
                            // if the displayimg-property attribute was not specified, default to the state's name
                            return currentState.name;
                        }
                        propertyReference = getObjectValue(scope.displayimgProperty, currentState);
                        if (propertyReference === false) {
                            return false;
                        } else if (typeof propertyReference === 'undefined') {
                            return currentState.name;
                        } else {
                            // use the $interpolate service to handle any bindings in the propertyReference string.
                            interpolationContext = (typeof currentState.locals !== 'undefined') ? currentState.locals.globals : currentState;
                            displayImg = $interpolate(propertyReference)(interpolationContext);
                            return displayImg;
                        }
                    }
                    //=======

                    /**
                     * Given a string of the type 'object.property.property', traverse the given context (eg the current $state object) and return the
                     * value found at that path.
                     *
                     * @param objectPath
                     * @param context
                     * @returns {*}
                     */
                    function getObjectValue(objectPath, context) {
                        var i;
                        var propertyArray = objectPath.split('.');
                        var propertyReference = context;

                        for (i = 0; i < propertyArray.length; i ++) {
                            if (angular.isDefined(propertyReference[propertyArray[i]])) {
                                propertyReference = propertyReference[propertyArray[i]];
                            } else {
                                // if the specified property was not found, default to the state's name
                                return undefined;
                            }
                        }
                        return propertyReference;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Check whether the current `state` has already appeared in the current breadcrumbs array. This check is necessary
                     * when using abstract states that might specify a proxy that is already there in the breadcrumbs.
                     * @param state
                     * @param breadcrumbs
                     * @returns {boolean}
                     */
                    function stateAlreadyInBreadcrumbs(state, breadcrumbs) {
                        var i;
                        var alreadyUsed = false;
                        for(i = 0; i < breadcrumbs.length; i++) {
                            if (breadcrumbs[i].route === state.name) {
                                alreadyUsed = true;
                            }
                        }
                        return alreadyUsed;
                    }
                }
            };
        }]);
})();
```

In the state router have under the data section added the image and display name 
for the particular icon click.

Breadcrumb template:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs">
        <!--ng-class="{ active: $last }"--><a ui-sref="{{ crumb.route }}" ng-if="!$last"><img ng-src="{{ crumb.displayImg }}" class="responsiveBCrumb" alt="" />{{crumb.displayName}}</a><span ng-show="$last"><img ng-src="{{ crumb.displayImg }}" class="responsiveBCrumb" alt="" />{{crumb.displayName}}</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Every template add this for dynamic menu

product.html

```
<h1>Product</h1>
<div class="note_panel note_panel_yellow">
    <div class="note_body note_panel_solid_border">
        <h4>Product Page</h4>
        <p>Sample Angular Breadcrumb</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research into how to use font icons. There are [a large number of tutorials on the internet about how to do that](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+use+font+icons&*). Try those out and if you have any questions, ask a new question here.

Comment: You've dumped a bunch of code on us and are expecting us to go through that code to figure out how it works and how to have it use font-icons. You've not shown what you've tried or any indication of research. Stack Overflow is not a place you dump your coding problems and expect people to do your work for you. Like I said, try something.

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan read the question and answer,just look into the demo part in plunker,you will get a idea about the issue,if interested.  there are lots of tutorials for font-icons,In angular uibreadcrumbs above  library have to use the font-icons under uirouter combination ,there is no blogs available for font icons for ui  angularbreadcrumbs.if you found anything ,just give one link.this is the below version of uibreadcrumb  i am using https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/uiBreadcrumbs

Comment: I'm not going to go to a different site and try and figure something out from your code. You can repeat the same comment as many times as you want, it won't change the fact that you are responsible for providing a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site. Read [ask].

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I have provide enough information about the peice of code, and given the demo for the issue, its too enough for answer  to the related problem, the problem is have to use font-icon instead of image, i am trying to implement font-icon , i just asked my question if it will help me   to do solve the issue .if you are familiar with angular and angular ui router have get a idea about the issue.